# Canvas: Click event on line

Tags: html, events, canvas, click, line

Please take a look at this little [example](http://jsfiddle.net/9V2Sq/). The clickhandler only works if you click in the middle of the line. It seems that the method `isPointInPath` does not consider the width of the line. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are correct.

The new isPointInPath() works only on the centerline of a "fat" line--not the full width of the line.

It's more user friendly on closed shapes that are more than 1 pixel wide ;)

A Workaround for your exact question: Instead of drawing a fat line, draw a 20px wide rectangle.

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/QyWDY/

This code uses basic trigonometry to create a rectangle around a line.  In the mousedown event handler, it redraws the rectangle transparently and then tests isPointInPath().

If you need to test a poly-line, you can use these same principles to make rectangle-lines for each segment of your poly-line.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    // get canvas's relative position
    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    // line specifications
    var x1=50;
    var y1=50;
    var x2=300;
    var y2=100;

    // draw the lineRectangle
    var lineRect=defineLineAsRect(x1,y1,x2,y2,20);
    drawLineAsRect(lineRect,"black");


    // overlay the line (just as visual proof)
    drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2,3,"red");


    function drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2,lineWidth,color){
        ctx.fillStyle=color;
        ctx.strokeStyle=color;
        ctx.lineWidth=lineWidth;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
        ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    }


    function drawLineAsRect(lineAsRect,color){
        var r=lineAsRect;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.translate(r.translateX,r.translateY);
        ctx.rotate(r.rotation);
        ctx.rect(r.rectX,r.rectY,r.rectWidth,r.rectHeight);
        ctx.translate(-r.translateX,-r.translateY);
        ctx.rotate(-r.rotation);
        ctx.fillStyle=color;
        ctx.strokeStyle=color;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    }


    function defineLineAsRect(x1,y1,x2,y2,lineWidth){
        var dx=x2-x1; // deltaX used in length and angle calculations 
        var dy=y2-y1; // deltaY used in length and angle calculations
        var lineLength= Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
        var lineRadianAngle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);

        return({
            translateX:x1,
            translateY:y1,
            rotation:lineRadianAngle,
            rectX:0,
            rectY:-lineWidth/2,
            rectWidth:lineLength,
            rectHeight:lineWidth
        });
    }


    function handleMouseDown(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // draw our lineRect
      drawLineAsRect(lineRect,"transparent");

      // test if hit in the lineRect
      if(ctx.isPointInPath(mouseX,mouseY)){
              alert('Yes');
      }
    }

    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown, false);

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=310 height=115></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have an example for drawing a rectangle instead of a line? I think it's quite difficult to do this if you want to create the lines by mousemoves and you don't know the line positions before.

Comment: Edited my answer to include an example for you :)